# 403 Forbidden on one specific page but it still loads correctly?

Tags: networking, http-status-code-403

Bit of an odd one.

I noticed some query string stopped working on page load for a page on my website. Upon checking the network console of chrome and firefox, I can see that the page is returning a **403 forbidden error**. This is odd, since the page seems to be loading correctly (except for query string not applying on page load).

It's the only page on the site that seems to be doing it.

Response Headers:

```
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
cf-cache-status: MISS
cf-ray: 463904819f55a71f-DUB
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 17:51:33 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
link: <https://ygoprodeck.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://ygoprodeck.com/?p=7620>; rel=shortlink
pragma: no-cache
server: cloudflare
status: 403
vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie,User-Agent
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

I'm not sure how it can both get a 403 and load properly at the same time, very odd.

The page in question: https://ygoprodeck.com/deck-search/

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

On the root of my site, I had a folder called "deck-search". No idea how it got there but it was causing issues. Removing it fixed it.