# WordPress page opening but with 403 forbidden status

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-403

Our website has been running since last 3 years, we were not sure when this happened exactly. Last week during testing we found out **few pages** are returning **403 Forbidden error**, but all those **pages are opening perfectly** in all browsers and OS.

One example is, https://www.jaicoupons.com/career/

Above page is working fine, but on HTTP header check, its returning 403 Forbidden.

[image: https://prnt.sc/qq1sgm]

Here are the things that i have already tried,

- Disabled WordFence, Sucuri, Really Simple SSL
- Updated permalinks.
- Replaced .htaccess with a default .htaccess

UPDATE: As mentioned by **Ken Y-N** its is fixed by removing the physical directory **Career**. That's also fixed the other pages as well, don't know how. Thank you.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614121/1270789) suggests that you have a physical directory called `career` that is confusing WordPress. BTW, there is also [wordpress.se].

Comment: I doubt on ACF plugin, can you please check once by deactivating it.